# Make overlay background click-through-able

Tags: css, background, transparent

Is there a way, in CSS, I can make an element click-through-able. I have an `absolute`ly positioned `<div>` covering a link. I'd like to be able to click the link *through* the overlay `<div>`. The overlay has a mostly transparent background, and the link has no covering pixels.

I've tried `background: url('...') transparent`, but to no avail.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jpCfz/6/) is a JSFiddle demonstrating my problem. The link can be clicked in IE8, but not in FireFox. What I want to do is make an image ticker in the `#underlay` div. The overlay is so that I can have a background with a gradient from solid to transparent on the bottom and top, so I can make the images sort of 'scroll into nothing', without fading the *entire* image out at once, if this makes sense (if anyone has an android phone, try scrolling your memos and watch the top/bottom of the screen - the memos fade into nothing).

Comment: @Knu: The overlay div is, like the thing it is overlaying, a block level element. Making a span `inline-block` or something might work.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I've fixed your problem by adding `pointer-events: none;` to the absolute block.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font: 20px Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 30px;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
#overlay-blocking,
#overlay-passing{
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 10em;
  left: 0;
}

#overlay-blocking {
  top: 30px;
  background: rgba(0,100,0, .2);    
  pointer-events: none;
}
#overlay-passing {
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(100,0,0, .2);    
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link blocked</a><br>
<a href="#" title="hoverable">Link available</a><br>
<a href="#" title="hoverable">Link available</a><br>    

<div id="overlay-blocking"></div>
<div id="overlay-passing"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! The original application for this has passed away, however this is awesome. How cross browser is it?

Comment: Answered my own question... It works in IE8, Opera 11.11 and Firefox 4. Do you have any other test cases?

Comment: IE6/7 - ok, chrome/safari5 (win) - ok

Comment: Not true! http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events , I tested on opera 11.11 and it is not working, maybe your test-case is broken

Comment: @Jakob Cosoroaba, that's right. pointer-events is not a fully-cross-browser feature. i had to use js as fallback(

Comment: pointer-events was the key. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible, because an image is still a complete box. But have you tried these [Image Maps](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_image_maps.asp)? Seems like that's what you want.

*OTHER OPTION*

You could also seperate your image into 2, and make sure that your boxes are not overlaying your link of course.

Comment: Thinking about it, I _can_ split the image. Thanks!

Comment: No, we don't split up images in 2011.  Use redundant elements if you must, but don't split up your image, there's no need.

Comment: @reisio - Yeah I was a little hasty in my response - splitting images didn't work :-(

Comment: @JamWaffles Did you try the image maps as well?

Comment: No - image maps are impractical for this situation as the underlaying content is animated via. jQuery. Thanks for the suggestion though :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this answer would be of some use to you, if you can nest the overlay inside the link: [With only CSS, is it possible to trigger :hover and click events underneath an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678176/with-only-css-is-it-possible-to-trigger-hover-and-click-events-underneath-an-el/2678716#2678716)

Comment: Re: Your edit: In that case, nope, the answer I found isn't helpful for you. I think the solution will have to involve JavaScript click detection. Do you want to go down that road?

Comment: No. It sounds like a dark and scary road :-(
Well, not that dark and scary, but not elegant.